# Given a focal length and an aperture of the telescope, what is its field of view?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, astronomy, lenses, telescopes

While I know FOV of scope is equal to FOV of eyepiece divided by magnification.

How can one find FOV given only the focal length and aperture of the telescope?